# Get first elements of List<string[]> to a string[] using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, type-conversion

I have a list of array of string: `List<string[]> myList;`

Is there any way to get an array of strings with all the elements string[0]?
Like List myList to string[] where elements are myList[string[0]]

I suppose it´s something like var result = from x in myList .Take(0) select x

And question 2)
is there any way to convert a string[] to string[1,] without a for loop?
Now I do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
      range[0, i] = arr[i];
```

I need "this syntax" because I´m exporting columns to excel. And I need an object[,] to do a `range.set_Value(Type, object[,])`.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, you should ask one questions at a time. If you have two different questions, ask two separate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string[] result = myList.Select(arr => arr.FirstOrDefault()).ToArray();
```

Is that what you're looking for?

`Take(n)` only returns an enumerable with at most `n` elements, so that's obviously wrong.

Comment: I thought `arr[0]` was fine. Can't see any advantage in using `FirstOrDefault()` here

Comment: @paul `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if there is no elements, as opposed to going _BANG!_.

Comment: I suppose it's up to @Alberto whether he would want it to go BANG! here, or whether his app should bravely continue on with an unexpectedly empty dataset

Comment: @GrantThomas Going *BANG!* when something unexpected happens is usually a good thing.

Comment: @svick An array without elements is hardly usually an unexpected thing, it's always quite plausible. Hence, it can be handled (or not, if desired) without it being _exceptional_.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather from your question, this should suffice:

```
string[] result = (from item in myList select item.FirstOrDefault()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first part;

```
var temp = myList.Select(q => q.FirstOrDefault());
```

For the second part;
I do not think there is a direct `Linq` statement to convert a single dimension array to a multi dimension one.

Comment: This will return an `IQueryable<string>`, to my knowledge.

Comment: @GrantThomas Why would it do that? Unless you start with `IQueryable` or explicitly call `AsQueryable()`, LINQ won't return that.